# tex to xml conversion through xslt

Tags: conversion, xml

I know latex, but new in xslt (learning now), I need to convert the tex to xml file through XSLT (one of my friend suggest, but i failed to convert). Please suggest or give example to convert the files (below is the MWE),

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\section{Section Head}

Sample Para text

\subsection{Section Head 2}
Sample Para text

\section{Section Head}
\subsection{Section Head 2}

Sample Para text

\end{document}
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear xslt is an xml transformation language so it is quite good at converting xml to tex but no use at all in the other direction. You need to convert the tex to xml _before_ you can process it with xslt., tex4ht, latexml and similar tools would need to be used for the conversion.

Comment: @david Carlisle Is possible to convert xml to tex through xslt ?

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran yes, it is possible to convert xml to tex through xslt. If you want the other way, from tex to xml, then you need to use latex to xml tool (such as tex4ht, which you already use, AFAIK). This generated xml can then be transformed to other xml formats through xslt.

Comment: Note that questions that are mainly about xslt are better suited on [so].

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no options to convert latex to xml using xslt and follow the below steps to get html output and then use xslt to convert html to xml.

1. Add tex4ht style file in your preamble as given below.
   \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage{tex4ht}
2. Compile your tex file in command prompt

> htlatex yourfile.tex
> and then you will get the yourfile.html

Thanks
Bala S